# Secure SQL Server connection through client application (how to protect reverse engineering)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, encryption

The requirement I have is that part of the install process for an application includes database setup and updates that require SA privilege, but the windows user installing will not have that password.

As a result, the thought is to use an installer application that embeds the sa password and will perform all required actions. This will further be secured by requiring a password to launch the installer based on some sort of algorithm that makes it unique on a daily basis.

Now, the concern I have is that (with the knowledge i have right now) it would be pretty simple to reflect the .net application to easily figure out the sa password. So, the question is how do I protect this. Obfuscation for sure, but it's never that good.

Comment: I have to ask -- are you requirements even _sane_? Phrased slightly differently, the question really is, _I'd like an untrusted user to be able to install and run a program that makes administrative changes to the computer. What's the least bad way to do that?_ I certainly wouldn't want to use a computing platform that made it trivial for untrusted user accounts to _ever_ run any programs that make administrative changes...

Comment: Have you thought about retrieving SA password through network?

Comment: This just sounds like an invitation for reverse engineering.  You are right, reflection would reveal in .Net but anytime you process strings with plain-text keys there are ways to retrive that data (even without reflection).  Even if you encrypt the string or key, the program must be able to retrieve it.  Therein lies your problem, I would definitely look at your system architecture for an alternate approach...

Comment: I agree with it all, especially that it's not really sane, but it's what I have to deal with (not my decisions). One thing i didn't mention was that there is no connection to the "outside" world. This is exactly what i've been telling my managers.....they just are not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* go to the level of encrypting portions of your application to hide the secret values - but if your application is able to decrypt it you need to store the key in the application too.

DVD players, are one good example of this - DVDs are encrypted using a system called [Content Scramble System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System), and each DVD Player manufacturer embeds a key to be able to decrypt DVDs, on the player itself.

The thing is though - if the end user's machine has the ability to run your code, then there's nothing you can do to truly prevent them from accessing the key. It's just a matter of time and effort for someone to figure out how, exactly, you've obfuscated that. Just ask "DVD Jon", the developer of the [DeCSS Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeCSS).

If you want to ensure security of information, don't put that information where a user can get to it. Host the database elsewhere and give the user credentials which have limited functionality.
Either that, or accept the fact that users will be able to bypass the security, and plan for that (eg: by not doing anything important locally).

Comment: Agreed I've looked into this in .Net just recently and, like any program, at some point the application must decrypt the phrase/key.  Alternate, limited credentials ran through some type of proxy or validation server-side is the only way to go.  DVD security is an excellent example.

Comment: Agreed. And, as I've just found out, it all doesn't matter anyway. http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/